# PDF Map write-in fields to variables for

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, canvas

I am looking to build a self-serve javascript app that enables a user to take an existing (flattened or scanned) PDF without interactive text input fields (like a lease document, or government form) and map variables to these traditional paper write-in fields so they can be populated by an app.

I have looked at a bunch of software but I haven't found something like this, I have looked at converting the PDF to a jpg and then using OCR to find the xy of the "______________" inputs; I have also looked at having the user draw a box over each of these areas to collect the xy coordinates; this is less desirable given the target users are 35-60 years old.

I wanted to throw this out to the community to see first if something that does this exists, and what libraries you would use to built this?  (Keep in mind it is user experience is key).  Also populating the PDF is not an issue as one could use itextpdf, this is specifically how one would map paper text areas.

-Thanks.

Comment: Personally I do not see how you can get away without having the user to draw the box. Not all documents are going to have "____________" perfectly arranged for you to try and parse from them to get coordinates. Other than that, Echosign from Adobe and several other products already do all the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the more that I look around the more I am thinking I will need to make it so the users can draw the text box.